# Failed to restore project when there is external nuget source configured

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have few configured in nuget.config nuget sources on my machine.

One of them (`externalSource`) look at external protected source (all the below generated by VS):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="externalSource" value="https://.external_source./nuget/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
   </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I **can** retrieve json configuration from all the sources on my machine in the browser where I can enter proper credentials (ie work with this without any issues). Also, I can easily work with this nuget source in `Nuget Manager UI` in VS.

The machine where I'm working on also has access to a different nuget source, but this source is not configured anywhere (in VS or any nuget.config).

Now, I create a simple console application:

```
PS C:\..> dotnet new console --no-restore
The template "Console App" was created successfully
```

note: I intentionally skipped restore to limit the question area only to `restore` logic, without this option, the `new console` command will fail, even though the project itself will be created.

Now I want to restore created application:

```
PS C:\..> dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source "https://.external_source./nuget/v3/index.json". [C:\..\test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\..\test.csproj]
```

When I enable, detailed logging verbosity, I see that failing happens in this step:

```
 1>Target "Restore" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets" from project "C:\..\test.csproj" (entry point):
   Task "RemoveDuplicates"
   Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
   Using "RestoreTask" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
   Task "RestoreTask"
     (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '4'
     (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False'
     (in) RestoreNoCache 'False'
     (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False'
     (in) RestoreRecursive 'True'
     (in) RestoreForce 'False'
     (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False'
     (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False'
     (in) RestorePackagesConfig 'False'
..

   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/vulnerability.update.json
     1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://.external_source./nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\..\test.csproj]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\..\test.csproj]
         Assembly loaded during TaskRun (NuGet.Build.Tasks.RestoreTask): System.Diagnostics.StackTrace, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.. (location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll, MVID: .., AppDomain: [Default])
         NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://.external_source./nuget/v3/index.json.
          ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
..
```

How can I fix it?

Configuration like:

- in nuget.config:

  ```
  <packageSourceCredentials>    
     <externalSource>      
        <add key="Username" value="name" />      
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value=".." />    
     </externalSource>  
  </packageSourceCredentials>
  ```
- or options for the `dotnet restore` command: `--interactive` or `--ignore-failed-sources` don't help. I can fix it with option `--source=nuget.org`, but I have to have `externalSource` configured since in some other cases restoring should happen from this source

**UPDATE:** The error is gone if I retrieve nugets via: `nuget search -take 10 -Source externalSource` (when I run it, I see no prompts or popup windows) just after the error, but only for approximately 30 mins, then it starts failing with 401 error again

**UPDATE2** Machine where the issue is reproducible is Windows 11 Enterprise, not sure whether it's important, but I didn't see any issues on Windows 10

**UPDATE3** It looks like another approach to solve the issue is to call `msbuild -t:Restore`. Does this sounds like dotnet binary issue after all?

Comment: What's your external source provider type? In some cases nuget can't handle custom nuget package source "out-of-the-box" and needs some additional plugins which allows for eg. authentication (this is the case when using ADO Artifacts for example).

Comment: @Jakub, nothing specific, just regular nuget source in azure

Comment: @Jakub, I think, it's not really related to the source, on other machines everything work well, I have issues only on particular virtual machines

Comment: Check your windows `Credential Manager`

Comment: @Artur I don't see anything related here

Comment: @Unnamed what do you mean by "regular nuget source in azure" - do you mean Azure Devops Artifacts Nuget Source?

Comment: @Jakub, yes, you're right

Comment: @AdamVincent, nope as well as `--ignore-failed-sources`, this looks like .net issue: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/9012

Comment: I see sorry, I missed the updates.

Comment: how about this thing? https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider

Comment: I saw it but it looks a bit more complicated than I expected and also expects logic dependent on  `--interactive`, so not sure whether it will help. Then I noticed that it's also TF related (see dotnet issue above) and might be a bug in .net8

Comment: the github issue looks oddly specific, like someone opened the issue on behalf of this post, I don't think it's an existing issue.

Comment: yes, it's related to this post. It contains a bit more repro details than mentioned here

Comment: `repro details` => for example that it works well with `msbuild restore` or `dotnet restore` in  .NET5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256311/discussion-between-unnamed-and-adam-vincent).

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is indeed downloading and setting up the [artifacts credential provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider)

When setting up a feed on Azure DevOps artifacts, you are provided instructions to connect to the feed from multiple sources. If we choose the instructions for dotnet CLI, we are shown the following:

---

[image: Project setup and a prompt to get the tooling]

[image: Tooling instructions]